# Removing Visual Composer head meta (works alone but not with IF)

Tags: wp-head

I'm trying to remove the head meta added by VC, namely "meta name="generator" content="Powered by Visual Composer - drag and drop page builder for WordPress".

If I add:

```
add_action('init', 'myoverride', 100);
function myoverride() {
    remove_action('wp_head', array(visual_composer(), 'addMetaData'));
}
```

it works and removes it. But what I want is to remove it IF installed, because if it isn't the above code throws an error obviously.

If I add:

```
if ( class_exists( 'Vc_Manager' ) ) {
add_action('init', 'myoverride', 100);
function myoverride() {
    remove_action('wp_head', array(visual_composer(), 'addMetaData'));
}
}
```

it doesn't work at all. I've checked the class name and it is correct. I'm  a PHP noob so any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

your problem boils down to doing things before the `init` hook was fired. You should never check for code existence, DB structure before it. In case of frontend related code you should not do anything before `template_redirect` hook.

Your code should be like

```
add_action('wp_head', 'myoverride', 1);
function myoverride() {
  if ( class_exists( 'Vc_Manager' ) ) {
    remove_action('wp_head', array(visual_composer(), 'addMetaData'));
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for using `wp_head` action hook. However, it's probably better to check for `function_exists( 'visual_composer' )` instead of `class_exists( 'Vc_Manager' )`. That way it'll work even if they change the class name in the future. On the other hand, if they change the function name, the `remove_action` will not work anyway.

Comment: Having said that, I've never used VC, so I don't know if the function `visual_composer` comes built in with VC or just a theme function. Hence I said *"probably better"*.

Comment: for me both methods are not reliable, and better to jusr not use a pluin that think that it can use your site for its own advertisement, but I never truly understand why anyone that can write php code like the OP demonstrates will even think about using a page builder.